# Getting console input with win32 api in x86 assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm, console-input

In my assembly program I called `AllocConsole` from the `kernel32` library, however I do not know how to get input from the allocated console.
Is there any function that the winapi contains that will get input from the allocated console in the current program?

```
CALL AllocConsole
```

All of the functions such as ReadConsole require an input buffer, and I do not know how to get the input buffer for my allocated console, let alone whether the function even does what I need.

To summarize, is there a function in the winapi that can get input from the allocated console in a program?

Thanks

Comment: Open `CONIN$` using CreateFile().

Comment: `AllocConsole` initializes standard input, standard output, and standard error handles for the new console. The standard input handle is a handle to the console's input buffer, and the standard output and standard error handles are handles to the console's screen buffer. **To retrieve these handles, use the `GetStdHandle` function.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All of the functions such as ReadConsole require an input buffer, and I do not know how to get the input buffer

The functions you have to call are the same in C and in assembly language. So your problem is not assembly language specific.

You can get the standard input and standard output handles using the `GetStdHandle` function.

To get the input handle you must pass the constant `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` (`-10` = `0xFFFFFFF6` in the case of a 32-bit program) as argument to the function.